# RegExp: Split line by ","

Tags: javascript, regex, regular-language

How to convert

```
"one,cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1), cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1), linear"
```

to

```
["one", "cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1)", "cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1)", "linear"]
```

How?

JavaScript.

This is not same. Becouse Quotation mark(left and right side), here ( - left, ) - right.

Don't work in JS.

```
'ease,cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1), linear,2,3'.split(/,(?=[^()]*((|$))/gi);
```

Result:

```
ease,(,cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1),, linear,,2,,3
```

Comment: what language? java, bash....?

Comment: I don't agree with the duplicate. Strings are really simple, here we want to parse a structured language (how do you manage nested parentheses?)

Comment: Will the input ever contain more than one level of ()?

Comment: Don't work in JS. 'ease,cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1), linear,2,3'.split(/,(?=[^()]*(\(|$))/gi); Result: ease,(,cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1),, linear,,2,,3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the parens cannot be nested (in which case you won't be able to use JS regex flavor).

Try this:

```
,(?![^()]*\))
```

A quick break down:

```
,          # match a comma                           [1]
(?!        # start negative look ahead               [2]
  [^()]*   #   match zero or more non-parens chars   [3]
  \)       #   match the closing paren               [4]
)          # stop look ahead
```

In plain English, that would read:

> *match a comma [1], only if there's no closing paren [4] ahead [2] without the presence of any paren between the comma and the closing paren [3]*

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example:

```
var str = "one,cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1), cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1), linear";
var arr = str.split(/,\s*(?!\s*\d)/);
console.log(arr.toSource());

// result
// ["one", "cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1)", "cubic-bezier(0, 0, 1, 1)", "linear"]
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3554U/1/)